# Getting module object is not callable when importing random into a function

Tags: python

Making a script as a project for my manager and getting an error on line 16 when trying to import random into the function and getting the module object is not callable on that line. Here is the code.

```
import time

import random

list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','+']

password = input('Enter a three character password')

guess = 0

while password != input:

import random
print('Loading, this is a test')
rannum = random('1','2','3')
if rannum == 1:
    ran1 = random.sample(list1)
    guess = ran1
    print(guess)
elif rannum == 2:
    ran1 = random.sample(list1)
    ran2 = random.sample(list1)
    guess = ran1 + ran2
    print(guess)
elif rannum == 3:
    ran1 = random.sample(list1)
    ran2 = random.sample(list1)
    ran3 = random.sample(list1)
    guess = ran1 + ran2 + ran3
    print(guess)
```

EDIT: I was able to clean the code up a decent amount to this:

```
import time
import random

list1 = ['A' , 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','!','@','#','$','%','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','+']

password = input('Enter a three character password')

guess = 0

while guess != password:
    rannum = random.randrange(1,4)
    guess = random.sample(list1, k =rannum)
    print(guess)
```

However whenever it prints it comes out looking like ['x' , 'v' , '1'] for example. Any idea on how to make it come out looking cleaner? So instead of that it would just come out like xv1?

Comment: You want to use method `random` from module `random`. So either `from random import random` or `random.random` when calling it.

Comment: Where did you learn to call `random` as if it were a function?  And why are you importing it multiple times?

Comment: I learned all my python from a questionable dude who learned to code like 20 years ago.

Comment: There are number of issues within your code too. you while will never break, is that by design?

can you edit your question with exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: This was mainly meant to test something, and yes the while wasn't meant to break, it was simply made to check something, and as a small project from my manager.

Comment: And the goal was to print a random assortment of characters ranging from 1 to 3 characters.

Comment: ```print(''.join(guess))``` will convert your list of characters to a string of chars.

Comment: And with this edited code how would I get it to stop whenever it guesses the password? Cause as of right now even if it guesses the password in the while loop it doesn't exit.